# Возможно ли реализовать тип данных более компактный и оптимальный чем String в Java?

Tags: java, строки, типы-данных, типы, теория-типов

Тип данных `String` (т.е. `public final class String`) в `Java 1.8` занимает 3168 строк исходного кода (включая все deprecated-методы).
Зачастую, никто не использует все возможности данного типа в конкретном проекте.

Ради спортивного интереса, хочется реализовать компактный тип данных а-ля `public final class CompactFastString` с минимальным набором методов и свойств.

Цель - более компактный с точки зрения используемой памяти и более быстрый для работы.
Цель больше лабораторная, нежели реальная.

Но существует мнение, что сложно реализовать более оптимальное решение, чем стандартная Java SE библиотека.

Что вы думаете на этот счет?

Comment: Все зависит от задачи. Если надо класс, позволяющий быстро конкатенировать строки - юзаешь StringBuilder, если надо чтоб был потокобезопасный - StringBuffer, методы, относящиеся непосредственно к строкам(типа split, matches, substr, etc.) в jvm оптимизированы настолько насколько это возможно(в основном). А количество строк в коде ни на что не влияет

Comment: что это вопрос-опросник, а по количеству строк производительность и потребление памяти не меряются

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Более быстрый в общем случае не получится. Стандартные типы пакета `java.lang` очень оптимизированы на уровне JVM. Тот исходный код, который вы видите в этих классах - для информации и дебага, а в реальности он заменяется на исключительно быстрые инструкции с учетом возможностей процессора. Например, сравнение строк будет не посимвольным, а с помощью пакетных инструкций SSE, которые умеют сравнивать по 4 байта за такт процессора. В этом и есть преимущество JIT компиляции.

P.S. Архитекторы виртуальной машины тоже не очень довольны занимаемой памятью под строки, поэтому планируется в будущих версиях сделать 2 режима  работы строк - utf-16 и только latin-1. Но опять же это будет на уровне JVM.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Про скорость понял. А в плане компактности по потреблению памяти есть соображения? Или тут счет на такой мизер по размерам идет что нет смысла обсуждать?

Comment: Дополнил ответ. Учитывая, что char занимается 16 бит, можно работать со строками как массивом байт. Но упаковка/распаковка руками и сложная работа с кодировками. Можно узнать конечную вашу задачу? Потому что от неё многое зависит.

Comment: Еще раз спасибо за ответ. Как таковой задачи нет. Просто личный профессиональный интерес и желание всесторонне развиваться в java. Думаю попробовать сделать реализацию некоей CompactSimpleString и сравнить по бенчмарку занимаемую память и скорость работы.